# Switching Button images in JS

Tags: javascript, image

I am new to Javascript (but experienced in other languages).

I am trying to switch the image on a button when it is clicked. Pretty straight forward, but for whatever reason this works one way but not the other. The second image (... In) doesn't change back to an Out image.

Additionally, it only seemed to want to work when I gave it the full URL (I have removed that in this example).

I realise that this is using 2 if statements and an else would be preferable, but it wasn't working like that either...

```
    <script>
    function SwitchBut()
    {
        //let x = document.getElementById("MyBut").src
        //window.alert(x)
        if(document.getElementById("MyBut").src == "But_Logout_In.png")
            {
                let x = document.getElementById("MyBut").src    //using for debugging
                window.alert(x)   //using for debugging
                document.getElementById("MyBut").src = "But_Logout_Out.png"
            }
        if(document.getElementById("MyBut").src ==  "But_Logout_Out.png")
            {document.getElementById("MyBut").src = "But_Logout_In.png"}
    }
</script>

<button><img ID=MyBut src="But_Logout_Out.png" onclick=SwitchBut()></button>
```

Comment: In this case using `else` would not be preferable, it'll be the correct thing to do, your code have logical errors if it uses `if` instead of `else`

Answer (score 0):

You need a few changes.
change this

```
<img ID=MyBut src="But_Logout_Out.png" onclick=SwitchBut()>
```

to this

```
<img id="MyBut" src="But_Logout_Out.png" onclick=SwitchBut()>
```

and change the second `if` to an `else`

```
if(document.getElementById("MyBut").src == "But_Logout_In.png")
  {
    let x = document.getElementById("MyBut").src    //using for debugging
    window.alert(x)   //using for debugging
    document.getElementById("MyBut").src = "But_Logout_Out.png"
  }
else
  {document.getElementById("MyBut").src = "But_Logout_In.png"}
```

note that your image isn't changing the second time because it enter's in both `if`'s.

As your button starts with `src="But_Logout_Out.png"` the first time you click the button, it won't enter the first `if` just the second one, then your image will have `src="But_Logout_In.png"`. The second time you click in your button it has `src="But_Logout_In.png"` so it'll enter the first `if`, change the `src` to `"But_Logout_Out.png"`. Because there's another `if` bellow, and it checks if `src="But_Logout_Out.png"`, it'll enter in this `if` too because the image `src` was modified seconds ago in the above `if`, so your image will have now `src="But_Logout_In.png"` again.

Comment: Doh!! Couldn't see it for looking - many thanks for your help.

One clarification please: what is the purpose of changing the   >  to a   /> in the img tag?

Comment: There's no need for that, it was just a typo, sorry for that, the only thing that matters is the `id` attribute. Did it work?